# stop reloading the entire page after Modal from submission in razor pages

Tags: forms, bootstrap-modal, razor-pages

I have a edit page like this

[image]

i have a comment button in this page,which is a modal form ,where users can leave their comment

[image]

when i submit the Comment form,the entire page is reloading and im losing the edit page content.
Im handling edit page content and comment box in two different forms.
So when i submit the comment form,the modal should open as it is and also the edit page content should not be gone.

This is my modal

```
<div class="modal modal_outer right_modal fade" id="information_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel2">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content ">
        <div class="modal-header bg-warning" style="height:50px;padding:10px 5px;font-family:'Delivery';">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Comments:</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body get_quote_view_modal_body">
            <div class="list-group">
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
                    <div class="d-flex w-100">
                        <h5><i class="fas fa-user"></i>&nbsp; User 1</h5>
                        <small class="ml-auto">1 days ago</small>
                    </div>
                    <p>This is for testing.Please ignore this.</p>
                </a>
            </div>
            <form asp-page-handler="SubmitChat">
                <div class="form-group mt-2">
                    <label for="TxtAreaChatBox"><b>Leave Your Comments</b></label>
                    <textarea asp-for="RequestChatBox.Comments" class="form-control" id="TxtAreaChatBox" rows="4"></textarea>
                    <input id="hdnCommentReqID" type="hidden" asp-for="RequestChatBox.RequestID" value='@Request.Query["RequestID"]' />
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fas fa-window-close mr-2"></i> Cancel</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

------------Edited-------------------

```
    <!---COMMENT BOX STARTS HERE-->
<div class="modal modal_outer right_modal fade" id="information_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel2">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content ">
            <div class="modal-header bg-warning" style="height:50px;padding:10px 5px;font-family:'Delivery';">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Comments:</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body get_quote_view_modal_body">
                <div class="list-group">
                    @if (Model.ShowRequestChatBox != null){
                    @foreach (var item in Model.ShowRequestChatBox)
                        {
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
                        <div class="d-flex w-100">
                            <h6><i class="fas fa-user"></i>&nbsp; <i>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CommentedUser)</i></h6>
                            <small class="ml-auto">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastModifiedTimeStamp)</small>
                        </div>
                        <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Comments)</p>
                    </a>
                        }
                    }
                </div>
                <form asp-page-handler="SubmitChat" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="post" data-ajax-complete="Completed">
                    <div class="form-group mt-2">
                        <label for="TxtAreaChatBox"><b>Leave Your Comments</b></label>
                        <textarea asp-for="RequestChatBox.Comments" class="form-control" id="TxtAreaChatBox" rows="4"></textarea>
                        <input id="hdnCommentReqID" type="hidden" asp-for="RequestChatBox.RequestID" value='@Request.Query["RequestID"]' />
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fas fa-window-close mr-2"></i> Cancel</button>
                        <button type="submit" id="BtnChatSubmit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--COMMENT BOX ENDS HERE-->
```

Javascript

```
function Completed(event) {
        if (event.responseText != "") {
            alert("Some Error Has Occured.Please Check Your Entered Values.");
            
        } else {
            alert("Your Comment Has Been Added Successfully");
            
        }            
    }
```

Thanks,
Teena

Comment: You need to submit the modal form using JavaScript instead.

Comment: @MikeBrind thanks for the hint. I have used jQuery Unobtrusive AJAX .Its working fine.I need one suggestion also.How can i make it real-time,which means when i click submit is it possible to show the comment without refreshing the page.

Comment: Return the comment as a partial and use the `data-ajax-update` attribute to perform a partial update: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/ajax/unobtrusive-ajax#partial-updates

Comment: @MikeBrind, im not using any partial page. The Comment Form is inside the same page which is a modal pop up.